# How to cache Geowebcache tiles from applications

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache

I have enabled disk quota to cache tiles that produced by WMS. Geoserver admin panel **Tile Caching->Tile Layers** list of cached layers. I can preview here on a demo page.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo/pgs:topas?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=image/png
```

After preview I see that disk quate increased. This works fine.

I am using my layers on my OpenLayers application but used disk quata is not increasing.
application is using url: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/.....`
 Used tiles are not inserting to disk. Why does not this?

(I have enable Tile **Caching->Caching Defaults->Enable direct integration with GeoServer WMS**)

Comment: What url is your app hitting?

Comment: I updated also question http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/...

Comment: You need to either hit the gwc url or match yor tiles to the gwc grid (unlikely by chance)

Comment: I set my custom projection as EPSG:99100 in epsg.properties file. I could not found geowebcache.xml in my server. should I create geowebcache.xml? I see only gwc-gs.xml in /geoserver/data path

Answer (score 2):

The chances are your OpenLayers application is requesting data in as a regular WMS request.

The following options will let you fix it:

- Make sure you meet all the requirements listed here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/using.html#direct-integration-with-geoserver-wms - the one you're most likely missing is `tiled=true` as a parameter in your requests.
- Use WMTS/TMS - ideal for basemaps, not so much other layers.